# Codeigniter Pagination does not work when clicked on further page link

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am working on Codeigniter Pagination and following this link :

> http://www.technicalkeeda.com/codeigniter-tutorials/pagination-using-php-codeigniter

but when i click on further links i.e. 1,2 and so on then the next sequence of records does not loads up only the initial (from 1 to 5 shows up) i have seen other links on stackoverflow : [CodeIgniter Pagination Page Links Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129452/codeigniter-pagination-page-links-not-working) but it did not work. My code is as follows, please help to solve my problem:

> Controller: home.php

```
<?php
class Home extends CI_Controller {


 public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('MovieModel');
        $this->load->library('pagination');
    }


 public function index($offset=0){

  $config['total_rows'] = $this->MovieModel->totalMovies();

  $config['base_url'] = base_url().'/home/index';
  $config['per_page'] = 5;
  $config['uri_segment'] = '2';

  $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="pagination"><ul>';
  $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul></div>';

  $config['first_link'] = '« First';
  $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
  $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';

  $config['last_link'] = 'Last »';
  $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
  $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';

  $config['next_link'] = 'Next →';
  $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
  $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';

  $config['prev_link'] = '← Previous';
  $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
  $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';

  $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
  $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';

  $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
  $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';


  $this->pagination->initialize($config);


  $query = $this->MovieModel->getMovies(5,$this->uri->segment(2));

  $data['MOVIES'] = null;

  if($query){
   $data['MOVIES'] =  $query;
  }

  $this->load->view('index1.php', $data);
 }
}
?>
```

> MovieModel.php

```
<?php
class MovieModel extends CI_Model {


 function getMovies($limit=null,$offset=NULL){
  $this->db->select("MOVIE_ID,FILM_NAME,DIRECTOR,RELEASE_YEAR");
  $this->db->from('trn_movies');
  $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
 }

 function totalMovies(){
  return $this->db->count_all_results('trn_movies');
 }
}
?>
```

> View: index1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
  <head>
   <title>Codeigniter Pagination Example</title>
   <link href="<?= base_url();?>css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">

       <h4>Movies List</h4>
       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
        <tr><td><strong>Movie Id</strong></td><td><strong>Film Name</strong></td><td><strong>Director</strong></td><td><strong>Release Year</strong></td></tr> 
        <?php 
        if(is_array($MOVIES) && count($MOVIES) ) {
         foreach($MOVIES as $movie){     
        ?>
        <tr><td><?=$movie->MOVIE_ID;?></td><td><?=$movie->FILM_NAME;?></td><td><?=$movie->DIRECTOR;?></td><td><?=$movie->RELEASE_YEAR;?></td></tr>     
           <?php 
         }        
        }?>  
       </table>            
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row"><?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?></div> 
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>    
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of the links generated by `create_links();` ?

Comment: echo $this->db->last_query(); in getMovies() model and check the offset and limit, while click the second pagination link

Comment: @AdrienXL : This is the link which is generated <a href="http://localhost/Myproject/home/index/5">2</a>

Comment: $query = $this->MovieModel->getMovies(5,$this->uri->segment(3)); third segment is 5

Comment: isn't the `http://` part missing ? Also have you done the necessary to remove `index.php` from your urls ? It should be `http://localhost/Myproject/index.php/home/index/5`. I guess

Comment: @msvairam:   using $query = $this->MovieModel->getMovies(5,$this->uri->segment(3)); works but when i ckick on first link it does not show 1-5 record it start from 6th record.

Comment: @msvairam: first link does not contain any links that must be the issue how to resolve that and highlight the link that is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below coding

```
if($this->uri->segment(3))

$offset = $this->uri->segment(3);

else 

$offset = 0;

 $query = $this->MovieModel->getMovies(5,$offset);
```

Comment: Thanks this is working but there is no link on the first link and the second thing is the current link are not getting highlighted.

Comment: Current activated links are added active class. You will apply style for active class

Comment: but what to do with the first link with blank href=""

Comment: Glad help to me, Can you upvote my answer, then move further

Comment: <a href>1</a> and clicking on that does not show 1 to 5 record how to resolve this issue

Comment: If click second pagination link, then check the 1st pagination link ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105115/discussion-between-user3653474-and-msvairam).

Comment: It did not contain any link only blank href <a href>1</a>